# Google Sheet: How to extract all values from a column which fulfils a condition to another column in Googlesheet using formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below table in Sheet-1:

| Name | Qty | CurVal | PrevVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 | 6.5 | 7.23 |
| DCE | 9 | 9.77 | 5.43 |
| EFG | 4 | 13 | 9.17 |
| LKD | 23 | 5.79 | 6.65 |
| RSB | 12 | 16.78 | 12.26 |
| TYR | 8 | 11.38 | 6.84 |

I would like to find and display only the Names, which fulfil below two conditions using Google Sheet formula:

1. PrevVal<8
2. CurVal>8

By these above conditions, I'm expecting to see Names==> DCE and TYR in Sheet-2.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A; Sheet1!D:D<8; Sheet1!C:C>8)
```

or:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A; Sheet1!D:D<8; Sheet1!C:C>8))
```